# Pass parameter to controller from @Html.ActionLink MVC 4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "BlogReplyCommentAdd", "Blog",
         new { blogPostId = blogPostId, replyblogPostmodel = Model,
         captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha })
```

I get the following runtime error on blogPostId:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'blogPostId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult BlogReplyCommentAdd(Int32,
>   Nop.Web.Models.Blogs.BlogPostModel, Boolean)' in
>   'Nop.Web.Controllers.BlogController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I have already assign a value for this on top such as

```
    @{         
        var blogPostId = Model.Id;          
     }
```

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult BlogReplyCommentAdd(int blogPostId, BlogPostModel model, bool captchaValid)
    {}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please give me an example.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

You are using a wrong overload of the [`Html.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper. What you think is `routeValues` is actually `htmlAttributes`! Just look at the generated HTML, you will see that this anchor's href property doesn't look as you expect it to look.

Here's what you are using:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Reply",                                                  // linkText
    "BlogReplyCommentAdd",                                    // actionName
    "Blog",                                                   // routeValues
    new {                                                     // htmlAttributes
        blogPostId = blogPostId, 
        replyblogPostmodel = Model, 
        captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha 
    }
)
```

and here's what you should use:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Reply",                                                  // linkText
    "BlogReplyCommentAdd",                                    // actionName
    "Blog",                                                   // controllerName
    new {                                                     // routeValues
        blogPostId = blogPostId, 
        replyblogPostmodel = Model, 
        captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha 
    },
    null                                                      // htmlAttributes
)
```

Also there's another very serious issue with your code. The following routeValue:

```
replyblogPostmodel = Model
```

You cannot possibly pass complex objects like this in an ActionLink. So get rid of it and also remove the `BlogPostModel` parameter from your controller action. You should use the `blogPostId` parameter to retrieve the model from wherever this model is persisted, or if you prefer from wherever you retrieved the model in the GET action:

```
public ActionResult BlogReplyCommentAdd(int blogPostId, bool captchaValid)
{
    BlogPostModel model = repository.Get(blogPostId);
    ...
}
```

As far as your initial problem is concerned with the wrong overload I would recommend you writing your helpers using named parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Reply",
    actionName: "BlogReplyCommentAdd",
    controllerName: "Blog",
    routeValues: new {
        blogPostId = blogPostId, 
        captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha
    },
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

Now not only that your code is more readable but you will never have confusion between the gazillions of overloads that Microsoft made for those helpers.

Comment: You need to change comments `controllerName` and `actionName`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: how to pass model as parameter?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov,@webdeveloper:Is i need to mention [httppost] on actionresult?

Comment: @NetraSW, you should not have an `[HttpPost]` in the action because the link is sending a GET request. `[HttpPost]` means that your controller action is accessible only with a POST request.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: HOw i can make this happend? model sends propeties value empty. Please guide me.

Comment: I already told you that you cannot send complex objects with an ActionLink. Did you read my answer? I repeat: you remove this parameter from your action arguments and you retrieve it using the `blogPostId` value from your underlying data store.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov:I don't have repository which gives me detail of Model by ID.How to add model to repository.It may look stupid question for you.But I need to know how can i do that?

Comment: You already did it in the controller action that rendered this view. You retrieved your model from somewhere in order to pass it to the view, haven't you? So you could use the same code in your `BlogReplyCommentAdd` action to retrieve the model from the same place.

Answer (score 12):

I have to pass two parameters like:

> /Controller/Action/Param1Value/Param2Value

This way:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText,
    actionName,
    controllerName,
    routeValues: new {
        Param1Name= Param1Value, 
        Param2Name = Param2Value 
    },
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

will generate this url

> /Controller/Action/Param1Value?Param2Name=Param2Value

I used a workaround method by merging parameter two in parameter one and I get what I wanted:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText,
    actionName,
    controllerName,
    routeValues: new {
        Param1Name= "Param1Value / Param2Value" ,      
    },
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

And I get :

> /Controller/Action/Param1Value/Param2Value

Comment: Apparently, this happens when Param1Value is null. I have just encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass values by using the below .

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home",new { name = ViewBag.Name }, htmlAttributes:null )
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult About(string name)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            ViewBag.NameTransfer = name;
            return View();
        }
```

And the URL looks like

```
http://localhost:50297/Home/About?name=My%20Name%20is%20Vijay
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be with the value Model.Id which is null. You can confirm by assigning a value, e.g

```
@{         
     var blogPostId = 1;          
 }
```

If the error disappers, then u need to make sure that your model Id has a value before passing it to the view

Comment: No, that's not the problem.