# MVC4 and jquery : Redirecting to another view using button and also sending parameter object (to another view)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Firstly I must say I new to MVC4 and learning and developing this application simultaneously.
In this application there is “index.cshtml” view, it contains “fresh” span (button).
 On click of this button I want :

1. to redirect on another view named “Interview”,
2. also want to send parameter “data” to view(Controller Action method)

**Index.cshtml view code snippet:**

```
.
.
some code
<span class="action-class" id="fresh">Start Fresh Interview</span>
.
.
some code
.
.
$("#fresh").click(function (e) {
            var tech;
            var guid = '@Model.currentInterviewDetails.GuId';
             $.ajax(
            {
                type: "post",
                url: '@Url.Action("Interview","Home")',

                data: {
                    GuId: guid,
                    IntervieweeName: $("#IntervieweName").val(),
                    LevelId: $("#SelectedLevelId").val(),
                    DId: $("#SelectedDesignationId").val(),
                    TrackId: $("#SelectedTrackId").val(),
                    TechId: tech
                },

                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
         });
```

But new view (i.e interview.cshtml) is not getting loaded and I can see the old view (index.cshtml)

**Interview.cshtml  code  snippet:**

```
@model InterviewAssistant.Models.CommonWrapper
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Interview";
}
@
@if (Model.tech != null && Model.tech.Count() > 0)
{
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedTrackId)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.SelectedTechId,
            new SelectList(Model.tech, "TechId", "TechName"),
            string.Empty
            )
}
```

**Below is the controller code:**

```
public ActionResult Interview(InterviewDetailsModel interview)
        {

            string name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            CommonWrapper wrapper = new CommonWrapper();
            wrapper.track = CommonWrapper.GetTracks();
            wrapper.level = CommonWrapper.GetLevel();
            wrapper.designation = CommonWrapper.GetDesignation();
            wrapper.currentInterviewDetails = interview;

            wrapper.tech = (from s in CommonWrapper.GetTechnology()
                            where s.TrackId == interview.TrackId
                            orderby s.TechName
                            select s).ToList();


            return View("Interview", wrapper);

        }
```

Can anybody please help me on this problem.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

In simple way you can make `Controller`

```
 public class DefaultController : Controller
{
   Public ActionResult Index()
   {
      Model model = new Model();
      model.TechId = "TechId here";
      model.TechName = "TechName";

      return View(model);
   }

    public ActionResult InterView()
     {
         return View();
     }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InterView(Model model)
    {
       //retrive model here 

       //return your interview view here
       return View("InterView");
    }
}
```

In Index.cshtml View:

```
@model namespace.model.modelname 

@using (Html.BeginForm("InterView", "Default", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitInterview" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: The model the form is submitting and the values being captured in the HTTPPOST method is not in sync. Edit and change it

Comment: @Reddy can't understand your comment can you explain it clearly ?

Comment: :) Sorry for my bad english I was typing fast and didnt realize the mistake.

Comment: No problem i have corrected the above problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

**HTML Helpers**

Why not try using some of the Razor HTML Helpers? You can always use jquery if you want, but if you are using MVC perhaps utilise some of it's core features! If you parameter is called 'interview' then do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me","Interview","ControllerName",new {interview= Model.currentInterviewDetails.GuId},null)
```

Where data is what you are sending down as a parameter, where Interview is the view name, and ControllerName is naturally, your controller name, the null is for optional HTML Parameters. If you had multiple parameters of, name, data, and age it would be this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me","Interview","ControllerName",new {name = "Glitch100",data = 4, age = 22},null)
```

This is the power of MVC4 - don't worry about making links yourself. If you wanted to do an AJAX call to it instead, simply use:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me","Interview","ControllerName", new {data= 4}, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "myIdToUpdate", OnComplete = "runMeOnComplete()"})
```

**BeginForm**

If you need to pass more information up, why not use a form? Better still have MVC build the form for you using your model!There are again two types - Html and AJAX!

*HTML BeginForm*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Interview", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitInterview" value="Submit" />
}
```

*AJAX BeginForm*

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "Interview", new {unitId = unit.Id}, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "interview-feedback", OnComplete = "startInterview()"}))
{
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitInterview" value="Submit" />
}
```

In relation to your Controller, if using a POST you will need to add the

```
[HttpPost]
```

attribute to your controller.

**Overloads:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

**Related:**

[Pass parameter to controller from @Html.ActionLink MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4)

Comment: But this option will render my view in that page itself.

Comment: If you use the AJAX options, then yes, but if you use the HTML.ActionLink it will redirect you there.

Comment: Do you want to render that Interview.cshtml to the screen? Then use one of the Ajax requests. In addition add the [HttpPost] attribute to your controller.

Comment: Yes I want to render Interview.cshtml to screen. I added [HttpPost] to controller but still it is not loading "interview.cshtml".

Comment: Then do what I have suggested - an Ajax.ActionLink - call your controller, use HttpPost, and specify an ID for the page that you want to render the Partial to.