# Combine link and button to one

Tags: asp.net

Have a look at this code:

```
<div class="widget bg">
   <h3>Kategorier</h3>
       <ul>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("BlogHome", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                 {
                     foreach (var group in Model.Categories.GroupBy(c => c))
                         {
                           <li><a href="#">@group.Key (@group.Count())</a></li>
                           <button value="@group.Key" name="cat">Click Me</button>

                          }
                  }
        </ul>
 </div>
```

This code gives me a button that submits to my controller..I would like the link itself to excecute the method so that i can get rid of the button. Any tips on how tp achive that?

EDIT:

```
//Kategorierlist
```

Here is the list of strings getting looped through in the view:

```
 var listOfCategories = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
              listOfCategories.Add(item.ChoosenCategory);
            }
```

EDIT:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BlogHome", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
                                {

                                    foreach (var group in Model.Categories.GroupBy(c => c))
                                    {

                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()">@group.Key (@group.Count())</a></li>
                                        <input type="hidden" value="@group.Key" name="cat" />

                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: So basically you want the link to submit the form instead of button?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the form an `id`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BlogHome", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
```

Then set the `submit` function as the onclick action from the anchor:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()">@group.Key (@group.Count())</a>
```

And keep the old value from the button in a `input type=hidden`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@group.Key" name="cat" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering...however..this does not seem to pass the value I previously stored in value="@group.Key"...

Comment: If you removed that code, yes it is gone. Try to create a input type="hidden" to store that value.

Comment: hmm this seems to send the same value everytime?

Comment: Which same value? Where is the code that changes the value?

Comment: Please see edit.
Model.Categories is a lsit of string containing different categories.
In my loop, the value getting sent is always the same...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with this code. Can you explain?

Comment: Sure!
The loop you helped me with loops through a list of strings representing categories in my blog..i.e music,movies,whatever..
The loop shows these categories and shows how many posts in that category.
What I would like is this:
When I click a link, the name of the category gets sent to a method that fetches all posts within that category. It worked when I had the button but i would prefer it if I could just klick the link.

Comment: I added the "complete" form in my question the way I understood it should be done

Comment: But you don't need a form for that, do you? Why not just create a link using `@Html.ActionLink`?

Comment: That was my first thought to, but how can I fit all the atrributes (the count, the key) into a actionlink? You have helped me plenty already but I would sure appreciate if you could update your answer with an actionlink =)

Comment: If the action has parameters, you can pass them just like you do with the `BeginForm` in my sample code. Check this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14152825/993547.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute `onclick="form.submit();"` on a tag to submit the form.