# Passing two parameters to controller with @Hml.ActionLink, but the second parameter value is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.Net MVC 5 application, I use the @Hml.ActionLink helper to call an action on a controller, where I need to pass two parameters. However, the second parameter always ends up with a null value.

Here is the view code, with ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Remove",
    actionName: "DeleteItemTest",
    controllerName: "Scales",
    routeValues: new
    {
        itemID = 1,
        scaleID = 2
    },
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult DeleteItemTest(int? itemID, int? scaleID)
{
   //...doing something here....
    return View();
}
```

This is the html that ends up on the page:

```
<a href="/scales/deleteitemtest/?itemID=1&amp;scaleID=2">Remove</a>
```

In my controller, I then end up with a value of 1 for "itemID", and null for "scaleID". What am I doing wrong?

Update - adding Route configuration based on request:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        // Ignore .axd files.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        // Ignore everything in the Content folder.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
        // Ignore everything in the Scripts folder.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
        // Ignore the Forbidden.html file.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Error/Forbidden.html");
        // Ignore the GatewayTimeout.html file.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Error/GatewayTimeout.html");
        // Ignore the ServiceUnavailable.html file.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Error/ServiceUnavailable.html");
        // Ignore the humans.txt file.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("humans.txt");

        // Enable attribute routing.
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly is the value returned from `@Html.ActionLink` being used?

Comment: Works fine for me - generates `<a href="/Scales/DeleteItemTest?itemid=1&scaleid=2">Remove</a>`

Comment: And for me too. What is his problem might be?

Comment: @haim770 - I'm using the itemID and scaleID values to get objects from EntityFramework, and then perform some deletions of entries in the database.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke/@Fabjan: In debug mode, when I break in the controller method, I see a value for the first parameter (in this case "itemID", but no value (null) for the second parameter. If I switch them around, to put scaleID first, then itemID, I get a value for scaleID, but not for itemID. The html looks right, so I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Previously, I thought it might be related to the routevalues being specified in the ending up in wrong position, which is why I've tried explicitly setting the parameters (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4)

Comment: It does not make any difference with order they are in. All that matters is the that the names of the route parameters match the names of the parameters in the method. As I say, it works fine for me.

Comment: Do you have any custom routes setup? If so, can you post them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're using attribute routing and MapMvcAttributeRoutes; do you have this route mapped?  If not, the default route will take precedence and take only the first parameter as the ID.

You'd need to add in a route that expects both parameters.

Something like this would be slapped onto the controller action:

```
[Route("{itemID:int}/{scaleID:int}", Name = "DeleteItemTest")]
public ActionResult DeleteItemTest(int? itemID, int? scaleID)
```

Please note that this is not exact code, just something to work from.