# retrieve model properties values inside GET method in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following `GET` method , that's a code to a create form

```
 public ActionResult Add_Product(string Product_ID)
 { 
        AddNewProduct sample = new AddNewProduct();

        return View(sample);
 }
```

this is the model class for that

```
public class AddNewProduct
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

this is that `create form`

```
    @model project_name.Models.AddNewProduct    

    <h4>Add New Product</h4>    

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">                
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product_ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
               </div>
         </div>

         .....

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to AddNewProduct", "AddNewProduct","Home" , new {Product_ID = Model.Product_ID})
</div>

    }
```

I can Insert a Product_ID using this view page .But Once I click this `Back to AddNewProduct` link and debug `AddNewProduct` I cannot see any value for `string Product_ID`

Why this model properties not bind well

Comment: Show us your `AddNewProduct` action code.

Comment: @kez...Check my updated answer now. I think by sending one `null` in the end of the parameters of `@Html.ActionLink` your issue will resolved.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you trying to do. The model you initially pass to the view has not set the `Product_ID` so you link is passing `null` back to the method again. To set the value, use `AddNewProduct sample = new AddNewProduct{ Product_ID = Product_ID }; return View(sample);` but then its not clear why you have a `DropDownListFor()` associated with that property. Do you want to pass the selected option value back to the method?

Comment: I don't have a `DropDownListFor()` helper in view ,

Comment: Sorry, I meant `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have , `Add_Product` GET method , Once its load its view , which is `Add_Product` view , I can see a create from with `Product_ID` text box ,(let say I inserted a value to this box) then using a button in this view I can go again that `Add_Product` GET method`Add_Product` GET method , but in this time I should get `Product_ID` as I previously inserted value,  hope you got what I meant , Ill explain further if not

Comment: To confirm, If you enter a value of say 2 in the textbox, do you want the link to send the value of 2 back to the method again - i.e. the url would be `/Home/AddNewProduct/2`?

Comment: yeah , exactly , it easier if I can handle this with complex object also?

Comment: Then you will need to use javascript/jquery to to dynamically update the url based on the value of the textbox. Will add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign value. Assign value of `Product_ID` which you are sending from get method to `Product_ID`  property of class

```
public ActionResult Add_Product(string Product_ID)
     { 
            AddNewProduct sample = new AddNewProduct();
            sample.Product_ID = Product_ID;
            return View(sample);
     }
```

Comment: Nope its still `null` here I'm using only one method that is `Add_Product` , and thats a `GET` method

Comment: Check if link of anchor tag contains Product_Id while clicking on it. Also check if there are any spelling mistakes or differences in parameter sending.

Comment: Nope checked on both  `anchor tag` and `any spelling mistakes` ,  anchor tag doesn't contains any value, always null, nothing wrong in spellings

Comment: Do u have any AddNewProduct get method on HomeController ?

Comment: So which method gets called when click on action link?

Comment: `Add_Product` `GET` method is call

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4 for different overloads of actionlink.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the value of the textbox to the `Add_Product()` GET method, you need to use javascript/jquery. Replace you `@Html.ActionLink(..)` with

```
<a href="#" class="back">Back to AddNewProduct</a>
```

and add the following script

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Add_Product", "Home")';
$('#back').click(function() {
    var id = $('#Product_ID').val();
    location.href = baseUrl + '/' + id;
}}
```

Note: `location.href = baseUrl + '/' + id;` assumes your have defined a specific route with `{controller}/{action}/{Product_ID}`, otherwise it needs to be

```
location.href = baseUrl + '?Product_ID=' + id;
```

Alternatively, change the method parameter to `string id` so it uses the default route

Note also that you will probably want to change the method to

```
public ActionResult Add_Product(string Product_ID)
{ 
    AddNewProduct sample = new AddNewProduct
    {
        Product_ID = Product_ID
    };
    return View(sample);
}
```

so that if you click the `Back to AddNewProduct` link, the view will display the previous value you entered.

Comment: No objection with your answer, but for knowledge, can I apply this answer with complex objects also ?

Comment: Sure (with some limitations). What are you actually wanting to pass to the method?

Comment: will I able to pass 15 objects values , that consisting with HTML tags , ? I'm gussing due long url , I'll not be able to pass , Am  I correct ?

Comment: Possibly not - it may exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. And it would create a really ugly url. But the fact you want to do that suggests a problem with your design.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `@Html.ActionLink` is the `actionName` but you sent the model name (`AddNewProduct`). Change it to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to AddNewProduct", "Add_Product","Home" , new {Product_ID = Model.Product_ID})
```

Or use this overload (You need to send null also when using this `ActionLink` overload):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to AddNewProduct", "Add_Product","Home" , new {Product_ID = Model.Product_ID}, null)
```

Comment: yes you're right done mistake , here , but once I change as you mentioned I can direct to the method , but null value for `Product_ID`

Comment: still its getting null , is this because with page refresh , `GET` method flush its model ?