# retrieve the model property value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following form

```
@model project_name.Models.AddNewProduct    

<h4>Add New Product</h4>    

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">                
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product_ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>            
    </div>
}
```

I want to get this model properties using jquery or javascript

for that I just followed approach like below

```
 @model project_name.Models.AddNewProduct    

<h4>Add New Product</h4>    

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">                
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product_ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div> 
        <div id="testid" class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" >
            <input type="button" value="Test" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>           
    </div>
}
```

then in javascipt

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var sampleID;

        $("#Product_ID").keyup(function () {
            sampleID = $('#Product_ID').val();            
        });

        $('#testid').click(function () {
            alert(sampleID);
        });
    });

</script>
```

But seems like this is not optimum approach me , `keyup` 
appreciate if can suggest good way to get these values once after courser out

Comment: Whats wrong with just `$('#testid').click(function () { alert($('#Product_ID').val()); }` but what is the element with `id="testid"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats the way, but is there any function to get that value without `.click()` ?

Comment: Not sure what your wanting to achieve - you could for example use `$("#Product_ID").change(function () { alert($(this).val()); })` to display the alert each time the user changes the value (and tabs out of the control)

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually this question occured due to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649082/retrieve-model-properties-values-inside-get-method-in-mvc)

Comment: In that question, Your `ActionLink()` will pass null because you never set the value of the `Product_ID` in the model before you pass it to the view. There is no need for to use javascript/jquery to solve that problem

Comment: @StephenMuecke but using following snippet `new {Product_ID = Model.Product_ID}` can't I assign a value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value of `#Product_ID` in click event of `#testid` using `$('#Product_ID').val()` like below.

```
$('#testid').click(function () {
    alert($('#Product_ID').val());
});
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: is there any function to get that value without `.click()` ?

Comment: Just use `$('#Product_ID').val()` where you want the value. @kez

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using razor then you can use @ to get it directly in jquery like so:

```
$(function() {
   var sampleID = "@Model.Product_ID";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typo in your JS. change kepup it to keyup.

This should work as expected.

```
$("#Product_ID").keyup(function () {
  sampleID = $('#Product_ID').val();alert(sampleID);    
  //or you can use
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The model is server-side only. If you need to do something with the values in the view, you handle it as if it's a regular HTML page and javascript.

If you want to grab the value of an input field, use the blur event that is triggered when focus is lost.

```
$("#Product_ID").blur(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});
```