# Html.ActionLink sending Id parameter to another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two controllers: **Transaction and CheckingAccount**

In My **Index** view of **Checking Account**, I got following:

```
<td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Deposit", "Deposit", "Transaction",new {id = item.Id) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Withdraw", "Withdraw", "Transaction", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
```

Edit, Details and Delete links work as it is supposed to be, which means they send `Id` link to `CheckingAccount` controller.

For the Deposit and Withdraw links, I want to direct them to the `Transaction` Controller with the same id. However, it directs to CheckingAccount controller again.

How could i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it to:

```
<td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Deposit", "Deposit", "Transaction",new {id = item.Id }, null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Withdraw", "Withdraw", "Transaction", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
```

Note the last `null` parameter. `ActionLink` helper have a little problems with lots of overloads so without `null` you basically use wrong overload that's why you don't get link that you need.

Here is a [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4):

> Here's what you are using:
>
> ```
> @Html.ActionLink(
>     "Reply",                                                  // linkText
>     "BlogReplyCommentAdd",                                    // actionName
>     "Blog",                                                   // routeValues
>     new {                                                     // htmlAttributes
>         blogPostId = blogPostId, 
>         replyblogPostmodel = Model, 
>         captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha 
>     }
> )
> ```
>
> and here's what you should use:
>
> ```
> @Html.ActionLink(
>     "Reply",                                                  // linkText
>     "BlogReplyCommentAdd",                                    // actionName
>     "Blog",                                                   // controllerName
>     new {                                                     // routeValues
>         blogPostId = blogPostId, 
>         replyblogPostmodel = Model, 
>         captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha 
>     },
>     null                                                      // htmlAttributes
> )
> ```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but why do we have to add null at the end?

Comment: Wrong overload used wilthot null

Comment: Sorry. I could not get that. Could you please elaborate a little bit more ?

Comment: @Landowner i add details

Answer (score 1):

You can send the Id parameter to another controller by using following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Data", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = item.Id, },null)
```