# Cant pass parameter from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult DeletePost(string id)
{
    this.posts.DeleteById(id);
    return this.Redirect("/Posts/All");
}
```

View:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("DeletePost", "DeletePost", "Posts", new { id = post.Id })
```

when I debug i can see that the post.Id is assigned the correct value in the view.
yet once I get to the controller action, string id is null.

wtf am i doing wrong?

Routing is standard:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Besides the good answer(s) below, please also read this article that explains why using a hyperlink to do a DELETE is generally not recommended: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ActionLink` like this (note last `null`):

```
 @Html.ActionLink("DeletePost", "DeletePost", "Posts", new { id = post.Id }, null)
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4)