# Controller is not getting Parameter value from ActionLink - MVC 5.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am putting my head in passing parameter value from an ActionLink to an ActionMethod in controller.

I have an ActionLink in PartialView. This PartialView is rendered using ExtentionMethod RenderAction in _Layout.cshtml. I want ActionLink to pass a parameter to controller ActionMethod which is getting `null` with relevant overloaded version of ActionLink.

My Route defaults are

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

My ActionMethod is

```
[Authorize]
[ActionName("UpdateUser")]
public ActionResult UpdateUserGet(string id)
{
   //var User = cRUDUser
```

RenderAction in _LayoutPage is

```
 Html.RenderAction("UserManagerPartial", "Home", new { CT = Content.Value });
```

Finally, ActionLink in UserManagerPartial is

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Profile", "UpdateUser", "Home",  new { id = Model.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm active" })
```

Comment: are you sure model.userid is returning value?

Comment: When you mouse hover over the Link does is show the correct URL in the status bar of the browser ?

Comment: is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4

Comment: @Usman, It actually can't be more silly than this. You are great!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out from @Usman's comment that problem was on other side. Unusually, I cleared few Entity before rendering the partial view. So, basically Model is not having id value but `null`. If you reading this after sometime check your all values in Model.