# How to get browser querystring in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I create my partial view with @Html.Action() like so:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "AreaMenu", new { Area = "" })
```

In the partial view's controller I'd like to get the browser querystring, unfortunately if I try to get it from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` I get url to the controller not what's in the address bar.

How do I get this?

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script>
    var location = window.location;
</script>
<div class="row">
    @Html.Action("Index", "AreaMenu", new { Area = "" })
    <!--Start Content-->
    <div id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
        <div id="ajax-content">
            <!--Start Breadcrumb-->
            <div class="row">
                <div id="breadcrumb" class="col-xs-12">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb pull-left">
                        <li>
                            <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })'>
                                <i class="fa fa-home"> </i> Nuclei
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = (string)ViewBag.AreaName })'>@ViewBag.CurrentModule.Name</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=''>@ViewBag.AreaView</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End Breadcrumb-->
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Content-->
</div>
```

Comment: Is [Uri.Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.query?view=netframework-4.7.2) what you're looking for?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think it is

Comment: If you want to get the query string of the current URL, @Zer0's right `Uri.Query` is the way to go. `AbsolutePath` doesn't include the query string.

Comment: Ok, an example please, as Uri.Query needs an object reference, where to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC treats this as a standalone request (as if you are entering this action in the address bar).  That is why are seeing the controller in the AbsolutePath and not what is in the address bar.

You could pass the querystring as a parameter in your Action.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152825/893543

OR

Couldn't the model you use to generate the page contain everything you need?  The query string is what was passed to the controller that made the page, just add the properties you need to the model?

Comment: I've added the full page to the question, it is a layout without model, or did you mean the partial view model? Not sure I'm understanding clearly, can you show an example please.