# HTML `id` attribute conflicting with ASP.NET MVC `id` convention

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Can someone please help me understand why this following code:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", new {id="backbtn"})
</div>
```

inside a **View** is rendering following HTML in the browser:

```
<a href="/Products/Index/backbtn">Back</a>
```

instead of following desired HTML:

```
<a id="backbtn" href="/Products/Index">Back</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the 3rd parameter of the method, the one you're providing the `id` to, is the one used to define route parameters , not HTML attributes. Use the 4th parameter instead, and leave the 3rd one as null:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", null, new {id="backbtn"})
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) for details of what each parameter of the method is used for.

Answer (score 1):

it's worked for me more detail [Pass parameter to controller from @Html.ActionLink MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "SomeAction", "SomeController",null, new {id = "someID" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong overload of the [`Html.ActionLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) method.

You are using this overload [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_), the third parameter are the routevalues, no `htmlAttributes`.

You should use the overload [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_), here, the third parameter are routevalues, but the four are `htmlAttributes`

So you just need to pass null to third parameter

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", null, new {id="backbtn"})
```