# Pass a string as parameter for a View in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, controller

I'm having a hard time googling this, but I can't find my issue and I find it weird as it seems this should be something really simple (Maybe i'm using bad keywords)...

Anyway I have an ASP.NET Application And I would like to pass a string parameter to a cshtml view.

From My index.cshtml I pass the parameter I want:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Crear saludo", "Create", new { nombreSeguidor = item })
</td>
```

This is the part where I'm lost... It receives the parameter correctly, but I'm unable to make use of the string on the Create.cshtml.

```
    // GET: Saludos/Create
    public ActionResult Create(string nombreSeguidor)
    {
        ViewBag.nombreSeguidor = nombreSeguidor; //This is my try on achieving the behaviour I want
        ViewBag.Seguidores_Id = new SelectList(_repositorioSeguidores.DameTodo(), "Id", "NombreTwitch");
        return View();
    }
```

It seems to receive Seguidores_Id correctly, but not my new parameter (The ViewBag.Seguidores_Id was create by Visual Automatically)

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Thxs for the reply:

It seems that the first answer was What I was looking for, but now I have other issues.

My intention on this view is to create an item with a model, but some of the variables will be created automatically. This is the model I have:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Saludo { get; set; }
    public string CreadoPor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Seguidores_Id { get; set; }
```

**Id** will be auto; **CreadoPor** will be an unique string if created this way (always the same); and **Seguidores_Id** will depend on the parameter "nombreSeguidor" We have passed.

So, in this view, the only variable I want to be editable is **Saludo**

How do I fill other variables? Until now, I was using this autogenerated-code:

```
@model string
@*@model TwitchWebApi.Models.Saludos*@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Saludos</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Seguidores_Id)*@

        <p>
            Crear saludo para @Model
        </p>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Saludo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Saludo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Saludo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreadoPor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreadoPor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreadoPor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Seguidores_Id, "Seguidores_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Seguidores_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Seguidores_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: *"It seems to receive Seguidores_Id correctly, but not my new parameter"* - Can you clarify what you mean by that?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where do you first observe something unexpected?  Which specific value is incorrect?

Comment: @Egon: Are you trying to pass the `nombreSeguidor` parameter from the `public ActionResult Create(string nombreSeguidor)` action method to the `Create.cshtml` view and you don't success?

Comment: [This link may have the answer you are looking for. Best of luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4)

Comment: David: There was a part where I was trying to create a new Viewbag with "nombreSeguidor" so I wrote: "ViewBag.nombreSeguidor = nombreSeguidor;".
But it was not working... There isn't an specific error but more ignorance about ASP.NET in general. The autogenerated code call the view with "return View();" and I just wanted to know How could I add new parameters to the called View.
Victor: Ya that's it! Though I've already achieved it, but i'm having other issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a string parameter from the `public ActionResult Create(string nombreSeguidor)` action method to the `Create.cshtml` view it is possible just make it like below:

```cs
// GET: Saludos/Create
public ActionResult Create(string nombreSeguidor)
{   
    ViewBag.Seguidores_Id = new SelectList(_repositorioSeguidores.DameTodo(), "Id", "NombreTwitch");
    return View((object)nombreSeguidor);
}
```

In the `Create.cshtml`:

```
@model string
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        The passed string: @Model
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even preferable to use the strongly typed view instead of using `ViewData` or `ViewBag`.